# question in vector calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble solving the following question:

> Suppose $x , y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $x \neq y$. Show that there is a continuous function
>   $f : \mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R$ with $f(x) = 1,f(y) = 0$, and $0 \le f(z) \le 1$ for every $z \in \mathbb R^n$.

Please help me out, I don't know where to get started. I tried proving that if inverse exist, and the inverse is continuous on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $x\le z\le y$  then function must be continuous on $\mathbb R$. But I feel like this does not prove anything.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

First, take a look at the function $f_1(z) = \frac{\|z-y\|}{\|x-y\|}$. Now, this function satisfies two of the conditions you need out of three. On the sphere, centered at $y$ and with a radius of $\|x-y\|$, it is bounded between $0$ and $1$.

Now, find another function $f_2$ outside the sphere and put the two functions together to construct your full function.

Comment: why is f2 necessary? f2 will just represent the domain outside of the sphere. doesn't f_1(z) already satisfy all the condtion?

Comment: @whoami $f_1$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(z) = \sin^2 ( (\pi/2)[(z-y)\cdot (x-y)]/|x-y|^2),$ where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product.